# Is it possible to realize communication between independent components in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I have two components. These components are located on different routes. **'CreateItem'** component gives me possibility to create new items. I store new items to array. Array will include new created items. I want send this modified array to component **'Main'** where I will iterate those items and display them as list.

Here is my code:

1) index.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import {Main} from "./components/Main"
import {CreateItem} from "./components/CreateItem"
import {CurrentItem} from "./components/CurrentItem"


render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div> 
            <Route exact path="/" component={Main}/> 
            <Route path="/create_item" component={CreateItem}/>
            <Route path="/item" component={CurrentItem}/>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

2) Main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

export class Main extends React.Component {

    render(){
        const ToCreateItemPageButton = () => (
            <Route render={({ history}) => (
                <button type='button' onClick={() => { history.push('/create_item') }}>Move to create item page!</button>
             )}
            />
        )

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Main Page</h1>
                <ToCreateItemPageButton/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

3) CreateItem.js

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

export class CreateItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            mainArray: [],
            item: {},
            item_id: 0,
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({item: {item_id: this.state.item_id, 
                       name:event.target.value}});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        if (this.state.item.name.length > 0) {
        this.state.mainArray.push(this.state.item);
        this.state.item_id = this.state.item_id + 1;
        let data = JSON.stringify(this.state.mainArray);
        localStorage.setItem('mainObject', data);
        this.setState(
            {mainArray : this.state.mainArray,
            item_id : this.state.item_id,}
        );
        event.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    render(){
        const ToMainPageButton = () => (
            <Route render={({ history}) => (
                <button type='button' onClick={() => { history.push('/') }}>Move to main page!</button>
             )}
            />
        )
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Create new item</h1>
                <ToMainPageButton/>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>
                          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </label>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

So all I want is to have possibility to transfer my **mainArray** from **'CreateItem'** component to **'Main'** component.

Comment: use Redux......

Comment: You could redirect and send data to the target redirection Component:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redirect and send data like that:

```
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/target-path',
  data: [/*your data*/]
});
```

and receive it on the target component so:

```
const { data } = this.props.location;
```

Comment: I can't do it , always get readonly err msg ! I try it from out side to edit also with no success.  also from other class and some more tests...

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - *Yes it's possible* using container component like in [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/560fyjnp/507/) example.

So the idea is to keep you array of items in a container state and pass it to "iterated" component as well as a callback for handling incoming item.

```
// container component
class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        array: ['Hello', 'Stack', 'Overflow']
    }
    this.handleOnAdd = this.handleOnAdd.bind(this)
  }

  handleOnAdd(item){
    this.setState({
        array: [...this.state.array, item]
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        // pass shared props to "display" component
        <ChildOneDisplay items={this.state.array} />  
        // pass a callback to CreateItem component
        <ChildTwoAdd onAdd={this.handleOnAdd} />  
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// display component

class ChildTwoAdd extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    ...
    this.handleAdd = this.handleAdd.bind(this)
  }
  handleAdd(){
    this.props.onAdd(this.state.item);
    ...
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <input
          name="item"
          type="text"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.state.item}
        />
        <button onClick={this.handleAdd}>Add Me</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

So all you need is to wrap your two routes with a container component and pass props to both of them as i did in this example.

```
// So your container should look like the following one

render(){
  return (
    <div>
       <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Main items={this.state.array}}/> 
       <Route path="/create_item" render={() => <CreateItem onAdd={this.handleAdd}/>}/>
    </div>
  )
}

// And render it as the following
<BrowserRouter>
  <Container />
  <Route path="/item" component={CurrentItem}/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Moreover i suggest looking at [`redux`](https://redux.js.org/) - this is the library for managing your app state.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey the Reason: why he need to connect everything if he just need to transfer data ?

Comment: @tariklefi not everything just two components where data should be shared. These two components become presentational components and `Container` component is a container. You can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0). This is one way from fixing this problem. Probably you have another one.

Comment: i just didn't see the need to implement a connection with Container or Redux since the need was just send the data and capture it. there are no considerable interaction i see.

Comment: @tariklefi This is how i understood the title & description of this question.

Comment: Yes The Reason, I see your view.